# Tkinter problems with GUI when entering while loop

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a simple GUI which run various scripts from another python file, everything works fine until the GUI is running a function which includes a while loop, at which point the GUI seems to crash and become in-active. Does anybody have any ideas as to how this can be overcome, as I believe this is something to do with the GUI being updated,Thanks. Below is a simplified version of my GUI.

GUI

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Python 3

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from Entry import ConstrainedEntry
import tkinter.messagebox
import functions

AlarmCode = "2222"

root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Interface")
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


ttk.Button(mainframe, width=12,text="ButtonTest", 
           command=lambda: functions.test()).grid(
             column=5, row=5, sticky=SE)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

functions

```
def test():
    period = 0
    while True:
        if (period) <=100:
            time.sleep(1)
            period +=1
            print(period)
        else:
            print("100 seconds has passed")
            break
```

What will happen in the above is that when the loop is running the application will crash. If I insert a break in the else statement after the period has elapsed, everything will work fine. I want users to be able to click when in loops as this GUI will run a number of different functions.

Comment: `time.sleep(1)` is exactly how you would fulfill the requirement "please freeze my GUI for one second".

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `time.sleep` in the same thread than your Tkinter code: it freezes the GUI until the execution of `test` is finished. To avoid this, you should use [`after`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) widget method:

```
# GUI
ttk.Button(mainframe, width=12,text="ButtonTest", 
           command=lambda: functions.test(root))
           .grid(column=5, row=5, sticky=SE)

# functions
def test(root, period=0):
    if period <= 100:
        period += 1
        print(period)
        root.after(1000, lambda: test(root, period))
    else:
        print("100 seconds has passed")
```

---

**Update:**

In your comment you also add that your code won't use `time.sleep`, so your original example may not be the most appropiate. In that case, you can create a new thread to run your *intensive* code.

Note that I posted the alternative of `after` first because multithreading should be used only if it is completely necessary - it adds overhead to your applicacion, as well as more difficulties to debug your code.

```
from threading import Thread

ttk.Button(mainframe, width=12,text="ButtonTest", 
           command=lambda: Thread(target=functions.test).start())
           .grid(column=5, row=5, sticky=SE)

# functions
def test():
    for x in range(100):
        time.sleep(1) # Simulate intense task (not real code!)
        print(x)
    print("100 seconds has passed")
```

Comment: Is there any detailed online explination of root.after, as my code wont use time in practice, this was just an example as my actualy code will monitor for input via and external connected device.

Comment: What I am trying to say is if I had a simple print statment within a while loop, this would cause the same issue.

Comment: @user1978826 I've updated the answer. I suggest you to edit your question to reflect the aclarations you mention in your comments.

Comment: Yes but in the above example when I try and use the root solution I just get a global root not defined error

Comment: @user1978826 That is because your functions are in a different file, so you have to pass `root` as an argument - as a side note, consider including this type of callbacks in the same file, and only move the non-GUI related functions to a separate module.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but the problem I have is that the way I have demonstrated my code is different on a button click this will call a function within a different class, from this function it will then call another function which will perform the execution. That is where the problems arise.